# Offset value to the Left

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to use the result of a calculation done on `bar_index==189` from before it was calculated.

Is it possible to do it somehow?

If I write `plot_to_the_past = ta.valuewhen(bar_index == 189, high-low, 0) plot(plot_to_the_past)`

the result is cannot be used from before it was calculated. I just need to use the result of a calculation from before it was calculated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use any result before it is calculated. Your script will be executed on every bar and the results will then be available.

You can, however, wait till the 189th bar to form, do your calculations and plot the result somewhere in the past.

## Edit:

`plot()` has an offset parameter which you can use to shift the plot in either direction.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var float diff = na

if (bar_index == 189)
    diff := high - low

plotshape(bar_index == 189, size=size.small)
plot(diff, offset=-10)
```

[image]

Comment: How could I do my calculations and plot the result somewhere in the past. after the 189th bar is formed? How Could I plot `high - low` for 189th bar in the past?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the offset parameter, but unfortunately this value cannot be used for any calculation in the past.